# Client-side throttling response from kubernetes kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I have a 3-node ubuntu microk8s installation and it seems to be working ok.  All 3 nodes are management nodes.

On only one of the nodes, I get an error message and associated delay whenever I use a **kubectl** command.  It looks like this:

```sh
$ time kubectl get pods
I0324 03:49:44.270996  514696 request.go:665] Waited for 1.156689289s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://127.0.0.1:16443/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
sbnweb-5f9d9b977f-lw7t9   1/1     Running   1 (10h ago)   3d3h
shell-6cfccdbd47-zd2tn    1/1     Running   0             6h39m

real    0m6.558s
user    0m0.414s
sys     0m0.170s
```

The error message always shows a different URL each time.  I tried looking up the error code (I0324) and haven't found anything useful.

The other two nodes don't show this behavior.  No error message and completes the request in less than a second.

I'm new to k8s so I am not sure how to diagnose this kind of problem.  Any hints on what to look for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a good [write-up](https://jonnylangefeld.com/blog/the-kubernetes-discovery-cache-blessing-and-curse) about the issue. For some cases `rm -rf ~/.kube/cache` will remove the issue.

Comment: So if I understand the issue correctly, the error message is more or less a natural result of the architecture of k8s, and there is no consensus on what a fix would look like.  So for now, the work-around is just to ignore the message.

Comment: Can you try to resume the explanation here? Because this blog could not exist in the future :D

Comment: For some cases this fix could be correct. For my case it hasnt brougth any change of the behaviour. The warning still exists. `12:41:04.334468    4784 request.go:665] Waited for 1.161945s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET...`

Comment: @snukone did you found the fix?

Comment: @Vishrant no, not directly. but the warning has disappeard for some reason without myself changing anything. one thing i remember could have been influenced the solution: our administration raised the ressources for the kubernetes api-server and we minized the traffic to the api-server a bit by deleting health-checks of our kustomizations. these two are the only ones that i can remember which could have had an impact on disappearing of the warning right now :)

Comment: @Vishrant additionally the kubernetes versions could be a factor, currently i am using: + kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.5", GitCommit:"c285e781331a3785a7f436042c65c5641ce8a9e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-03-16T15:58:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.17", GitCommit:"22a9682c8fe855c321be75c5faacde343f909b04", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-08-23T23:37:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: "disappeared for some reason" it could be because of your local discovery, try cleaning the `~/.kube/cache` directory next time, if this does not work try increasing the side-side throttling `configOrDie.RateLimiter = flowcontrol.NewTokenBucketRateLimiter(rest.DefaultQPS*10, rest.DefaultBurst*10); mgr, err := ctrl.NewManager(configOrDie, ctrl.Options{...}`

Answer (score 1):

I had a same error with kubectl on Windows. Deleting "http-cache" folder in ".kube" fixed it problem. c:\Users****.kube\http-cache\

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).